# "Seu" antes de um nome?

Tags: significado

Porque se utiliza *"seu"* antes de um nome?

**Ex:**

- Seu Jorge
- Seu Cuca

Answer (score 17):

Segundo o dicionário [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/seu) uma das utilizações da palavra seu é:

> 12. Redução popular em próclise, de senhor (ex.: Como vai, seu Jaime?).

O mesmo também ocorre com a palavra "Santo" que se torna "São" (ex: São Mateus, São Paulo).

> [...]A [próclise](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal-proclise-mesoclise-enclise/) é responsável pela redução da extensão fonética de alguns vocábulos dissílabos[...]
>   [Fonte][3](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=zX9OknMLdUIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

**Nota:** Cabe avisar  que o uso da palavra "seu" em substituição a "senhor" só é válido no português brasileiro.

Comment: Só se usa no Brasil, recomendo uma nota na resposta. ;)

Comment: @E_net4. Só vale para a palavra "seu" ou para "são" também? Em Portugal é comum usar Santo Paulo?

Comment: James em Portugal também se usa o *São Paulo* e o *São Victor*, é a  Freguesia onde moro.

Comment: Em Portugal "São" já é comum. Só não é o uso de "seu" para tratar alguém por senhor.

Comment: Em Portugal, mais do que comum, é obrigatório usar _São_ para todos os santos com nome começado por consoante (exceto _h_, imagino). Creio que não há diferença nenhuma em relação ao Brasil.

Comment: "São" se usa antes de consoantes, e "Santo" antes de vogais. São Pedro vs Santo Antônio.

Answer (score 9):

Vale lembrar que: mesmo o `Seu` sendo uma redução popular do termo `Senhor`, o uso também é apenas para casos coloquiais. Exemplo: você encontra o seu vizinho no elevador do prédio e então o cumprimenta: `Como vai Seu Luís?`.

Não substitua o `senhor` por `seu` em nenhuma situação formal, pois não é bem visto

Comment: Acho que não seria um vizinho  para outro. Assim se fala aos porteiros do edificio. Tambem há um elemento de classe. A pessoa de classe mais alta segue o uso popular no sentido de que, nas classes populares.  isso mostra um certo respeito.