# Como "Senhor" virou "Seu"?

Tags: etimologia, fonologia

Essa [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/867/2764) explica a redução de "Senhor" para "Seu" (e também de "Santo" para "São") como sendo simplesmente uma

> redução da extensão fonética

Se trata mesmo apenas disso: um encurtamento baseado no som da palavra?

<sub>**Obs**: Questão inspirada pela postagem de [user 11652](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/11652) em ["Seu" antes de um nome?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/866/2764).</sub>

Comment: Pois isto é uma questão interessante, Eu custa-me a crer que este *seu* resulte exclusivamente de evolução fonética, sem influência do pronome *seu*. Mas não vi nenhuma discussão do assunto. Agora, juntar o *seu* e o *são* numa só pergunta é que não me parece grande ideia. Só o *seu* já é trabalhoso...

Comment: @Jacinto Feito. Tinha mesmo ficado na dúvida sobre por as duas.

Comment: Stafusa, eu te pergunto para testar minha sanidade nesta questão: as palavras *sô*, possivelmente *siô*, e *sinhô*, nesse sentido, são iguais a *seu*, não? Admito que nunca ouvi *sô* senão para imitar *meinerin*, mas o resto já usei.

Comment: @Schilive Entendo que sim também, que sejam grafias não padrão da mesma palavra, só não conheço o "sô" com esse sentido.

Comment: @Schilive e Stafusa, *sô* é a única que eu já usei. Agora, eu não concordo que isso sejam simplesmente grafias diferentes da mesma palavra. *Tranqüilo* e *tranquilo* são grafias diferentes da mesma palavra; mas *sô, siô, sinhô* e *seu*, para mim, são palavras diferentes mas sinónimas (como *há/faz muito tempo que não o vejo*). Se alguém diz *seu*, tu não vais grafar *sô* nem vice-versa, ou vais?

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, foi um comentário rapidamente escrito, a la chat, e me expressei mal, elas não são rigorosamente a mesma palavra — mas acho que também não são como "lhufas" e bulhufas" (diferentes mas equivalentes), mas sim, ou como "tá" e "está", quase uma mesma palavra, "senhor", mas faladas em dialetos diferentes (e.g., em certos grupos, especialmente com menos estudo formal, se pode dizer "sinhô" ao invés de "senhor", ou "adevogado"/"adivogado" para "advogado", etc.).

Comment: E **nhô**, que é freqüentemente usado em [Chico Bento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turma_do_Chico_Bento)?

Comment: @GuiImamura Sim, tem mais essa. Para mim ela soa mais como mesmo uma simples redução, _senhor_ -> _sinhô_ -> _nhô_ .